# Como evitar que o ember-data faça uma requisição ao servidor

Tags: javascript, emberjs, ember-data

Tenho uma rota em que a pessoa pode selecionar itens de uma lista para a sua conta. Mas ao entrar nessa rota ember envia uma requisição `GET` para o servidor. Com poderia evitar que isso aconteça?

Segue trecho do código. Estou usando EmberJS 2x

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    searchPlaces: Ember.inject.service(),
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    },
    afterModel(model) {
        let token = model.get('token');
        let places = model.get('places');

        this.set('places', places);
        this.set('token', token);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo essa resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256030/how-prevent-ember-data-send-request-to-server/35258573#35258573)

O problema está em usar o `findAll` ao invés do `peekRecord` ou `peekAll`. Ao ler a documentação sobre [DS.store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) podemos encontrar os seguintes casos.

- [findRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord) - retona uma promessa, primeiro consulta na memória e depois no servidor caso não seja encontrado.
- [findAll](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll) - É parecido com o `findRecord`, mas consulta todos.
- [peekRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekRecord) - retorna o resultado do item que já está na memória, ou `null` se não encontrado; não faz a consulta no servidor.
- [Relacionar o item](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekAll) - retorna um Array com os resultados encontrados e que já estão na memória.